# Difficulty calling R2OpenBUGS

Tags: r, winbugs

I am having a problem calling R2OpenBUGS.
I suspect it is probably simple to fix but I can't spot the solution.

My call looks like this:

```
    MCMCres<-bugs(data=d,inits=inits,parameters.to.save=c("theta","alpha","tau","precv"),
          n.iter=2000,model.file="model.txt",n.chains=2,n.burnin=250,n.thin=5, 
          OpenBUGS.pgm=BugsDir,codaPkg=F,working.directory=wdir,debug=T,WINE=NULL)
```

The error I get back is as follows:

```
    Error in bugs.run(n.burnin, OpenBUGS.pgm, debug = debug, WINE = WINE,  : 
    Look at the log file in  C:/Users/James/Desktop/ALS Spatial Analysis/ALS  and
    try again with 'debug=TRUE' to figure out what went wrong within OpenBUGS.
```

Now OpenBUGS isn't even opening so the log file is not written. I'm not sure whats going on since this is all I have to go on. It is finding the OpenBUGS executable and it is finding the model file as those were errors I had gotten previously and have fixed.

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: I might try to run a very simple model with BRugs and R2WinBUGS using as few options as possible in the bugs statement.  And maybe with WinBUGS directly without calling R.  Then using OpenBUGS directly without calling R.  Just to see if I can get any results at all.  Then try the very simple model with R2OpenBUGS using as few options as possible in the bugs statement.  Gradually add options to the bugs statement.  If you cannot run a very simple model with WinBUGS or OpenBUGS without calling R then your computer probably cannot find those applications, so maybe try re-installing them.

Comment: Thanks Mark,
Well the funny thing is - if I manually open OpenBugs and then use the script, data and inits files that is created by the bugs command above - then OpenBugs runs fine. So it seems like its a problem with R2Openbugs itself somehow. It would not be a problem except that I want to use snow to parallelise OpenBugs and I can't do that if I run it manually. I have played with removing options but so far no luck

Comment: If the model runs in OpenBUGS directly, but not when OpenBUGS is called through R, maybe R cannot locate OpenBUGS.  I do not know what to do, but I myself would try re-installing R, OpenBUGS and the required packages.  Do you have the most up-to-date version of all of them?  Sometimes using an old version of R or R packages can cause problems.

Comment: Well I think it is finding OpenBUGS because previously I had an error where it could not find openbugs and I was able to fix that by giving it the right directory and it stopped complaining about that.
Hmmm I have OpenBUGS 3.2.2. I have R 2.15 - but taking your cue I just download R 3 and got same problem there

Comment: Sorry.  I do not think I can offer additional suggestions, at least not without the complete code and an example data set so I could try to run it myself.  But even that might not help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark I appreciate your efforts. No I think it wouldn't solve it either as I've tried a lot of different things (I also suck at simulating data). At the end of the day I just wanted to make things faster since my model takes hours to run, but it does run manually and I can get things done....just more slowly :D
Thanks again!